# Creating Settings view in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, settings

This question must have been solved multiple times by many people, however after several hours of research I still haven't found what I'm looking for.

What I have is a `ExportSettings.settings` file with a bunch of settings (bools, strings, ints, etc) and I want to create a View for them. In order to do it I've created a simple window in which I've placed  standard buttons as `OK`, `Cancel` and `Close` and linked them to a `KeyDown` event to let the user accept/cancel using Enter/Escape.

I've created in XAML the needed `Checkbox`, `TextBox`, etc, for my settings. When the ExportSettingsView class starts, in its constructor I read my settings and assign the value for each control. In past I bound them directly but that unables the cancelation of changes, so I discarded it. When the user clicks `OK` button I assign, again, code-behind each value for each settings. If he clicks `Cancel` no assignment is done and the window just closes.

I would like something like EditableObject for my settings to avoid this ugly looking way of making my SettingsView.

Some of the things I'm looking for are:

- Being able to put some comments in my settings would be nice (ToolTip)
- Autogeneration of controls using reflection?
- Avoid creating custom settings class (and the work of saving and reading everytime the application starts/shutsdown)

Comment: this may be a starting point: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032450/automatically-represent-binding-object-by-correct-control)

Comment: Make a view model class with a bunch of backing properties it shouldn't take more than an hour to do depending on how many settings there are.

Comment: how about using a property grid?

Comment: @pushpraj Are changes in a property grid revertable if the user clicks cancel?

Comment: By default no, edits are sent to the bounded property as control loses focus. But I think we can trick it to do this for us. Most important point before we opt for same is the appearance. If you have some picture of the desired in mind, perhaps you can share the same. May I give a try for you.

Answer (score 4):

Break you problem up into parts to use MVVM, create your window and bind it to another class (ViewModel), this class will have properties on it that reflects the data in your settings file. this class also has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. It can also implement EditableObject if you want, but frankly it isn't needed.

Hook you buttons up to Commands on your VeiwModel so that when the user hits save, it writes its properties to the settings file.

In this instance:

- Window is your View
- The new class is your ViewModel
- Settings file is your Model

This will allow you to cancel changes, just dont write to your settings file when the user hits cancel.

The biggest point is that you DONT bind to your properties settings directly.

If you want auto generated fields for the view youll have to use a property grid, but with MVVM, your view is decoupled from you model so changing from things like textbox and such to a propertygrid would be easy.

When you do a search for MVVM, dont be fooled by people using a lot of terminology, MVVM is a very simple concept, it boils down to three classes, your View (xaml), View Model (what the view binds to) and Model (your data), THATS IT! good luck

Comment: Regarding the possibility to _not_ update properties if the user cancels, what do you think about using [`UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) property? This property "Updates the binding source only when you call the UpdateSource method", so you can call it upon `OK` but not on `Cancel`. (Great answer by the way)

Comment: (well, actually after some search I found out the promising [`BindingGroup.BeginEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinggroup.beginedit.aspx) method...)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need something like this http://wpfdataform.codeplex.com/
And if you use ReSharper you can easily generate wrapper class for your settings

Answer (score -2):

.NET already supports very nice tool for saving application and user variables. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx
It has to be saved explicitly so it might suit you very well. You can check what type the variable is and create a suitable control.